# Getting 'builtin_function_or_method object has no attribute ' Error while reading all worksheets from Excel file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm trying to read all excel files from current directory and all worksheets from each file.
When I try below code with single worksheet it works fine but when I try it with multiple worksheets then it gives below error

> ```
> for row in df.values.tolist(): AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'tolist'
> ```

Below is my code:

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.xlsx"))

df_email = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
df=pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)

for row in df.values.tolist():
    for col in row:
        matches = re.findall(regex, str(col))
        if matches:
            df_email = df_email.append([matches[0]], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: have you checked what df actually looks like once you have run your first for loop?

Comment: no, I haven't checked that. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the `sheet_name` parameter of the `read_excel` function.
If you do not specify the sheet_name value, `read_excel` return DataFrame (read first sheet of the excel file). However, if you specify the `sheet_name` value (sheet names as a list or None), it returns a dictionary of DataFrame. (see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Thus, you have to use `df.values()` to get each sheets in the excel file because the type of `df` is not `DataFrame`, it is `dict`.

Try to print the type of the df, as follows:

```py
path = os.getcwd()
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.xlsx"))

df_email = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    df=pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    print(type(df)) # You expected DataFrame, but it is a dictionary.
```

Comment: Thank you @Park . But when I'm using only df.values() I'm getting empty dataframe.

Comment: @Rushi Then, that means the sheet is empty. As I said, the `df` is a dict. You can check the sheet name and value of each sheet through `print(df.keys())`, `print(df.values())`, and `print(df.items())`.